# Cant seem to get anything to print

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to get a CSV file to print out - on my first step to being able to manipulate it - but whenever I run the program in Spyder all I get out is:

> "runfile('C:/Users/wf5931/OneDrive - Documents/Python Scripts/ExcelTest')"

Nothing ever seems to print.

**The data file is:**

```
Date (Period Beginning) ELEC - From ELE Network (kWh)   Reading Status
01/01/2018 00:00    8   OK
01/01/2018 01:00    9   OK
01/01/2018 02:00    10  OK
01/01/2018 03:00    14  OK
01/01/2018 04:00    3   OK
01/01/2018 05:00    2   OK
01/01/2018 06:00    0   OK
01/01/2018 07:00    19  OK
```

**Code:**

```
def excelTest():
    import csv
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        your_list = list(reader)
        print(your_list)
```

Comment: Why is there a pandas tag? Would using `pandas.read_csv(file)` work?

Answer (score 1):

You define a function `excelTest()`, but you don't actually call the function. Just add a function call `excelTest()` to the bottom.

```
def excelTest():
    import csv
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        your_list = list(reader)
        print(your_list)

excelTest()
```

Or make it more flexible, by making the filename an argument of your function:

```
def excelTest(file):
    import csv
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        your_list = list(reader)
        print(your_list)

excelTest('data.txt')
```

Comment: BTW: best thing normally is to add all imported modules to the start of the script. In this case, if you would call `excelTest()` multiple times, it would import `csv` again everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Columns in your csv file splited by `"\t"`, so you need to specify that in `csv.reader` constructor.

```
 import csv

 with open('data.txt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
     next(reader)  # skip header line
     your_list = list(reader)
     print(your_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas package to read csv,excel or any other files.That would be much more convenient then using the csv package.

Have a look at the code below

```
import pandas as pd
filename = "some_file.{file_extension}"
```

to read csv file

```
file_data = pd.read_csv(filename,sheet_name="Your sheet name")
```

to read excel file

```
file_data = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name)
```

to display the data

to print all data

```
print(file_data)
```

to print few data

```
#this will only print top 10 rows
print(file_data.head(10))
```

Hope this helps

Thanks